# Remove Dropdown Value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, show-hide

I'm trying to get rid of option value 2 whenever radio button 3 is ticked, this is what I've got based on what I've seen in similar questions but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Any suggestions?

```
<input name="options" type="radio" value="1" id="option1">
<input name="options" type="radio" value="2" id="option2">
<input name="options" type="radio" value="3" id="option3">

<select name="number" id="number">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option></select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
    $('#option3 input[type=radio][value=3]').attr('checked',true); 
        $("#number option[value='2']").remove()
});

</script>
```

Many thanks :)

Comment: do u want to permanently remove it when clicked on ration button 3 or , u just want to hide it when radio button 3 is clicked , them when you click on radio button 2 it should appear again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to the change event, currently you are trying to check the third radio button and delete the option on DOMReady.

```
$(function(){
   $('input[name=options]').change(function(){
       if (this.id == 'option3') {
           $("#number option[value='2']").remove()
       }
   })
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rDp24/

In some browsers you cannot hide an option element, you can remove the  option and append it again, try this:

```
var option = '<option value="2">2</option>';
$('input[name=options]').change(function() {
    var $select = $("#number");
    if (this.id == 'option3') {
        $select.find("option[value='2']").remove()
    } else if (!$select.find("option[value='2']").length) {
        $select.append(option)
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zszqs/

Comment: Both these work, however after choosing option 3 then going back to one of the other options value 2 doesn't reappear.

Comment: @undefined the new code doesn't work, when I changed the .hide to .remove that worked again but the .show doesn't. I know you need to use the .remove for this but not sure what the opposite option should be.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$('#option3').change(function(){
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("#number option[value='2']").remove();
            }
   });
});
```

it will remove the value

Comment: I'm getting an error if I leave in the brackets you have on the last line, when I take them out it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you

```
$("#number option[value='2']").val('');
```

Comment: That will still leave the `option` intact (so you can still see it). I doubt this is what the OP desires?

Comment: It will works fine bacause he op wants to remove the dropdown value when he clicks the second radio button

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/m3K2c/

a variation version here.

making radio button `option3` selected will `hide` the option

making other radio button (`option1` & `option2`) selected will `show` the option again.

Comment: Value 2 doesn't disappear when I click on option 3.